# Quota by quota id using ovirtsdk

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to use ovirtsdk to create ovirt machine. I tmust have a reference of quota. I have only quota id. How do I create the VM using ovirtsdk?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you in Python SDK version 4:

```
import logging

import ovirtsdk4 as sdk
import ovirtsdk4.types as types

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename='example.log')

# This example will connect to the server and create a new virtual machine with specific quota:

# Create the connection to the server:
connection = sdk.Connection(
    url='https://engine40.example.com/ovirt-engine/api',
    username='admin@internal',
    password='123',
    ca_file='ca.pem',
    debug=True,
    log=logging.getLogger(),
)

# Get the reference to the "vms" service:
vms_service = connection.system_service().vms_service()

# Use the "add" method to create a new virtual machine:
vms_service.add(
    types.Vm(
        name='myvm',
        cluster=types.Cluster(
            name='mycluster',
        ),
        template=types.Template(
            name='Blank',
        ),
        quota=types.Quota(
            id='8ed65137-1260-4ac1-bd67-c399cca2d75d',
        ),
    ),
)

# Close the connection to the server:
connection.close()
```